# Style input elements within sublevels of divs

Tags: css

I have a page like:

```
<div class="loginpage-form">

  ...some stuff

  <form>
  <div class="flexwrapme">
    <input type="text"... />
  </div>

  <input type="submit".../>
  </form>


  <!-- DONT apply Style to inputs from form below -->
  <form>
    <input type="text"... />
  </form>

</div>
```

This is a very basic question, but it's not clear to me : how do I properly style just the input type "text" or "email" **within** the loginpage-form > flexwrapme containers?

I had the following, but not convinced... :

```
.loginpage-form .flexwrapme input[type="text"],
.loginpage-form .flexwrapme input[type="email"] {
  style stuff...
}
```

Am I writing this correctly?

Cheers! Pat

Comment: What do you mean by properly styled ? This should work fine as well.

Comment: See edit. I mean I want to make sure to apply the style ONLY to the loginpage-form > flexwrapme > inputs ... as opposed to all inputs on page. Am I writting my CSS properly for selecting the right inputs here?

Comment: Yes you are writing correctly. it will only affect the those inputs.

Comment: I am asking, because I had a glitch with bootstrap invalid-feedbacks.. In short, MY inputs have a "background" color and "border" styling. However, if I added the "is-invalid" to have the invalid-feedback show (and place red borders around input box with exclamation mark ), it (bootstrap) wouldn't put the exclamation mark in the input box to mark the error. I ended up having to change MY styiling to be just input[type="text"] { ... } but that affects ALL inputs on page.

Comment: Alright. So I am writting it correctly. My bug must be somewhere else then. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Its definitely something to do this with bootstrap in that case. because it should just work fine as per the question above. Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ng5m7z21/

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add .loginpage-form for your style just this will do

```
.flexwrapme input[type="text"],.flexwrapme input[type="email"]{
your style
}
```

And one more easy way to do this would be to directly add class to your input elements and styling them

Comment: Strangely enough, if I try with your `.flexwrapme input[type="text"],...` or my full way above, I have the bootstrap/invalid-feedback bug. However, I tried just having my style in a .inputBox {...} and adding class inputBox directly into my inputs and THAT WORKS! I now longer have the glitch I was having... Strange. I'd like to understand why...